# PowerApps and Power Platform is a SAAS or PAAS?

Tags: power-automate, powerapp, powerapps-forms

I am wanted to know whether Powerplatform is a Saas or Pass?
As per my understanding it comes under Microsoft 365/Office 365 subscriptions and the subscription comes under Saas model. So, it should be Saas. But some blogs mentions it as PAAS. So, got confused.

Please help me clarifying this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Microsoft's official documentation, mentioned that Power Apps is **a Software as a Service (SaaS) platform**.

[image]

> **Ref:** [Key advantages of Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/transform-infopath#key-advantages-of-power-apps-over-infopath)

**However,**

- Some people consider it as PAAS because they can build apps without worrying about the underlying infrastructure, Thus, it would qualify as PaaS.
- On the other side, it's a SAAS because its subscription comes under SAAS Model.

In addition to the opinions expressed above, based on the diagram below and my feeble knowledge of the deployment models, I believe it's **PAAS** Since it’s a list of tools that are provided to build your own custom applications, it would qualify as Platform as a Service. however, I can consider it as a new hybrid deployment model called `PAAS-SAAS` :)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for clarification

Answer (score 0):

Based on the response here:
"Based on Microsoft's official documentation, mentioned that Power Apps is a Software as a Service (SaaS) platform.

enter image description here

Ref: Key advantages of Power Apps

However,

Some people consider it as PAAS because they can build apps without worrying about the underlying infrastructure, Thus, it would qualify as PaaS.
On the other side, it's a SAAS because its subscription comes under SAAS Model.
In addition to the opinions expressed above, based on the diagram below and my feeble knowledge of the deployment models, I believe it's PAAS Since it’s a list of tools that are provided to build your own custom applications, it would qualify as Platform as a Service. however, I can consider it as a new hybrid deployment model called PAAS-SAAS :)".

I would say that Power Platform is PaaS, because is the Platform Service where you run Power Apps, which is SaaS. Power Apps is a SaaS solution that is used to build other apps or even SaaS.